# issue with install newest version of ruby on cetos

Tags: ruby, centos, rvm, yum

Please help!!! 
I have issue with installing new version of ruby in my Centos6. 
I'l try install it using rvm :

```
/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm install 1.9.2
```

And got the next message :

> Error running 'requirements_centos_libs_install libyaml-devel
>   readline-devel libffi-devel sqlite-devel', showing last 15 lines of
>   /usr/local/rvm/log/1439995406_ruby-1.9.2-p330/package_install_libyaml-devel_readline-devel_libffi-devel_sqlite-devel.log
>   If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
>          can remove the one with the missing update and everything
>              will work.
>
> You have duplicate versions of libffi installed already.
>     You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.
>
> ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
>     this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
>     do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
>     much more problems).
>
> Protected multilib versions: libffi-3.0.5-3.2.el6.i686 != libffi-3.0.9-1.el5.rf.x86_64
>   ++ return 1
>   ++ return 1 Requirements installation failed with status: 1.

I try to remove this lib but again fail :

> Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected

Can somebody explain where I fail? Please! Thx all!

p.s. I'm update the system (in case if answer will be "yum update") :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove lib :

```
rpm -e --nodeps libffi
```

and again try to install ruby.